# Restrict specific IPs using Virtual Host in Apache

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I need to control few 100+ Ips using Apache’s Virtual Host. I have tag inside tag with below config.

```
<Directory “/usr/…”>
 …
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
..
</Directory>
```

Can anyone tell how to mention all 100 IPs in Directory tag?

Comment: what have you tried? have you check the [`mod_authz_host` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives)?

Comment: By adding "Allow from 127.0.0.1" inside Location element works but not sure how to mention multiple IPs. Is there way to specify the many IPs?